# Normalização de dados em uma rede neural

Tags: redes-neurais

Estou estudando sobre o uso de redes neurais e aprendi que os dados de entrada devem ser normalizados para que as funções de ativação não operem nos intervalos de saturação, é comum o intervalo de normalização ser [-1,+1]. Porém, para normalizar os dados de entrada devo conhecer o *range* dos mesmos. Minha dúvida é: Se eu não detenho o *range* destes dados, como posso normaliza-los?

Comment: se você não tem os dados, como pretende treinar a rede?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem os dados use o maior e o menor como range, ou verifique o maior e o menor e a partir deles estipule um range que considere aceitável.

A partir do momento que possuir o range pode normalizar com a formula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]